# Complex integration: pole of order 2 at zero

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula, cauchy-principal-value

Fix $a>0$. The following integral seems to be related to a complex integration:
$$
\int_{0}^{a}\frac{e^{-z}+z-1}{z^2}dz.
$$
We see that $f(z):=\frac{e^{-z}+z-1}{z^2}$ has a pole of order 2 at $z=0$. However, the upper end is a fixed positive real number $a$ instead of +∞ in which case usually can be dealt with a Cauchy integral. Is it possible to study the integral by complex analysis?Please give me some help or hints. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually, $f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$ since $\lim_{z\to 0}zf(z)=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please teach me how to calculate the integral since $a<+\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Since the function is analytic (once the removable singularity is removed), all integrations along curves do not depend on the curve itself, only the endpoints.

Since $a$ is a real number, one curve connecting $0$ and $a$ is the real interval $[0,a]$. I.e., you can treat this as a function on the real line and perform the real integration. Any other curve connecting $0$ and $a$ would give you the same result.

Comment: This would require to take an antiderivative of the function, right?

Comment: This requires integrating a real function over a real interval, just like in Calc I.

Comment: Yes, I agree. In calc 1, students primarily use the fundamental theorem of calculus and evaluate the antiderivative at the end points of the interval. However, upon first glance, it doesn’t seem this function has an antiderivative expressed in terms of elementary functions. I could be wrong though

Comment: I have tried $\frac{e^{-z}+z-1}{z^2}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-z)^j}{(j+2)!}$, but the overall integration does not seem to admit a simple closed form. Could you please give me some further comments?

Comment: Not every integral has a nice closed form anti-derivative. In fact the majority do not. Sometimes you can exploit the conservatism of complex analytic functions to find a nice answer to a specific integral without having to find anti-derivatives. But usually you cannot and I do not see a way here. You could maybe solve it in terms of the $\text{Ei, Si, Li}$ functions, but I fail to see that as any improvement, as these are no easier to calculate actual values than the integral itselt. Integrating your series representation will give you a means of calculating values to any accuracy you need.